# Qwt: curve with padding

Tags: qt, qwt

I want to draw curves with padding(Rounding the corners). I searched but nothing found. Is there any information about this?

This is how to i draw curves in qwt:

```
    QwtPlotCurve *curve =  new QwtPlotCurve;
    curve->setPen(QColor(color),width);
    QPolygonF p;
    p<<QPointF(x1,x2)<<QPointF(x1,x2);

    curve->setSamples(p);
    curve->attach(this);
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you mean with "padding"? Is a wider brush not sufficient? :)

Comment: Are you looking for `RoundCap` on your pen? Like here? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpen.html#cap-style

Comment: Sorry my poor English. I was try to say rounding the corner. :)

Comment: ... or maybe `RoundJoin`? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpen.html#join-style

Comment: What about my answer, is it helpful? I didn't get any feedback.

Comment: Yeah your answer was very helpful. Thanks for interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set special attribute:

```
QwtPlotCurve *curve = new QwtPlotCurve;
curve->setCurveAttribute(QwtPlotCurve::Fitted, true);
```

Not fitted:

[image]

Fitted:

[image]